# Values from Array with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm doing a relation between users and now i want to access the values from an embedded_in document with Mongoid that generates something like this, i need the friendlist:

```
>> 

current_user

=> #<User _id: BSON::ObjectId('57a4df6927d8754bd68aaade'), contacts: [{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('57a4df7a27d8754bd68aaadf'), "created_at"=>Fri, 05 Aug 2016 18:48:26 UTC +00:00, "friendlist"=>[BSON::ObjectId('57a4df6927d8754bd68aaade'), BSON::ObjectId('5790f58a27d8757b4ff547fd'), BSON::ObjectId('5790f43727d87576358ae575')], "owner"=>"57a4df6927d8754bd68aaade", "updated_at"=>Fri, 05 Aug 2016 18:48:26 UTC +00:00}], created_at: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 18:48:09 UTC +00:00, email: "testauth@myApp.com", haveFiles: false, image: nil, location: nil, updated_at: Mon, 08 Aug 2016 15:39:31 UTC +00:00, username: "testauth">
```

Here the line i need:

```
"friendlist"=>[BSON::ObjectId('57a4df6927d8754bd68aaade'), BSON::ObjectId('5790f58a27d8757b4ff547fd'), BSON::ObjectId('5790f43727d87576358ae575')]
```

My code looks like this

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @listofusers = User.all
    User.find_by(id: current_user.id).where(contacts: [friendlist]) do |listofcontacts|
      puts "***list of contacts***"
      puts listofcontacts
    end
  end
end
```

**Models**

User

```
## Customable ;)
  field :username, :type => String
  field :haveFiles, :type => Boolean, default: false
  field :location, :type => String
  field :image, :type => String
  embeds_many :contacts 
  embeds_many :favlists
  # Validate the presence of type username
  validates_presence_of :username
```

Contact

```
class Contact
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :owner, :type => String
  field :friendlist, :type => Array
  embedded_in :users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do this:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @listofusers = User.all
    puts "***list of contacts***"
    User.in(contacts: current_user.id) do |user|
      puts user
    end
  end
end
```

This will work if `contacts` is an array of `BSON::ObjectId`s. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: this don't solve, we just have only one ObjectId the other elements on the array is Owner and a friendlist array, is in the friendlist where it is the ObjectId's. I added the models for more information on the data structure.

Comment: This line `User.find_by(id: current_user.id)` is equivalent to `current_user` i guess

Comment: So far, what i get (apart from the model data given above), that you have a user `current_user` and want some friendlist for that user. So, do you want all the `friendlist` from all the `contacts` of a user? Please explain.

Comment: yes, we need to retrieve the embedded document and access to his properties.

Comment: from the current_user, something like this for understand: current_user.contacts.friendlist.all

Comment: `current_user.contacts.map(&:friendlist)` should work.

Comment: `current_user.contacts.map(&:friendlist)` returns something like this
57a4df6927d8754bd68aaade 
5790f58a27d8757b4ff547fd 
5790f43727d87576358ae575 

But on views just one object with all the line.